# How do I make use of await and async in this function?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm working on a Chrome extension that's almost finished. Currently, I get the response from my fetch as the data is being fetched completed, instead of the correct order. I guess I'll have to make use of await and async but I'm not sure how. Worth noting is that I have a "connection" between my background script and my content script using sendMessage.

I did try following this tutorial and it's probably extremely easy to follow if you have done it before, but I didn't understand what to do with my price => {}
Tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20201227111539/https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp

Content.js

```
function getPrices() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            {contentScriptQuery: "queryPrice", itemURL: skins[priceNumber]},
            price => {
                console.log(price);
            });

        priceNumber = priceNumber + 1;
    }
...
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.contentScriptQuery == "queryPrice") {
        var url = "https://pixelboii.wtf/steamvalue.json";
        var skinFullName = request.itemURL;
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(price => {
              sendResponse(price.items_list[skinFullName].price["7_days"].average);
            })
            .catch(err => { throw err });
        return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
      }
    });
```

All replies are appreciated!

Comment: the code you've shown suggests you sendMessage once ... so how can the response be in the wrong order?

Comment: If you're calling sendMassage in  some sort of loop - show how you're doing it - because the first code wont benefit from async/await as there are no promises in that code

Comment: Oh absolutely, updated the post!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by correct order.

Comment: Correct order: The first item to be fetched should also be the first item returned, the second item should be the second item to be returned etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch (and many other async methods) take an indeterminate amount of time to run. That is why they are asynchronous, they depend on some external resource which can take a variable amount of time.

You can't ensure the order of response is the same as the order of the calls. What you *can* do is send the `request.itemURL` in the `sendResponse` call as a second argument, and then in modify your callback to use that as well, e.g.

Content.js

```js
...
(price, url) => {
    console.log(`${url}: price: ${price}`);
});
...
```

Background.js

```js
...
sendResponse(price.items_list[skinFullName].price["7_days"].average, request.itemURL);
...
```

That will ensure you can keep track of which items have which price.

If you definitely need them to be in a certain order, you will need to wait until all of the callbacks are fired. This can be done by using a counter and incrementing before calling `sendMessage`, then decrementing within the callback. Some quick and dirty code to do this:

```js
let counter = 0, results = {};
for(let i=0;i<35;i++){
    counter++;
    sendMessage(..., (price, url) => {
        counter--;
        results[url] = price;
        if(counter == 0){
            // finished all calls
            // print results
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
}
```

To directly answer the question being asked: You would have to create a wrapper for `sendMessage` that returns a promise, then use something like `let results = await sendMessageWrapper(...)`. Using await in a loop is an anti-pattern though, as [this eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop) explains.

Comment: I feel like that's probably the best way to go about it, but instead of the itemURL I would prefer priceNumber since that's what I'll be using later to identify them. However, when I used your code it just returned undefined: price: undefined

Comment: If you want to use the priceNumber, you'd have to pass that to the background page and back again, or you could create a closure in your loop to capture the value at the time the `sendMessage` function was called. You should read up on closures and using callbacks in loops to fully understand what's going on here.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I understand how to make use of the code with priceNumber. My point is that even when I just tried your code (without priceNumber) it didnt work. I really appreciate the fact that you explain everything though!